# Python 2.7 with Pandas: How does one recover the non intersecting parts of two dataframes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have two data frames and the second is a subset of the first.  How do I now find the portion of the first dataframe that is not contained in the second one?  For example:

```
new_dataframe_1

    A   B   C   D
1   a   b   c   d
2   e   f   g   h
3   i   j   k   l
4   m   n   o   p


new_dataframe_2

    A   B   C   D
1   a   b   c   d
3   i   j   k   l


new_dataframe_3 = not intersection of new_dataframe_1 and new_dataframe_2


    A   B   C   D
2   e   f   g   h
4   m   n   o   p
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit:  I initially was calling the intersection the union, but have since changed this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, one way to do this is using `isin` (but you can also do it with the `merge` command ... I show examples for both). For example:

```
>>> df1

   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
1  e  f  g  h
2  i  j  k  l
3  m  n  o  p

>>> df2

   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  c  d
1  i  j  k  l

>>> df1[~df1.isin(df2.to_dict('list')).all(axis=1)]

   A  B  C  D
1  e  f  g  h
3  m  n  o  p
```

Explanation. `isin` can check using multiple columns if you feed it a dict:

```
>>> df2.to_dict('list')

{'A': ['a', 'i'], 'C': ['c', 'k'], 'B': ['b', 'j'], 'D': ['d', 'l']}
```

And then `isin` will create a booleen df which I can use to select the columns we want (in this case require all the columns to match and then negate with `~`):

```
>>> df1.isin(df2.to_dict('list'))

      A      B      C      D
0   True   True   True   True
1  False  False  False  False
2   True   True   True   True
3  False  False  False  False
```

In the specific example we don't need to feed `isin` a dict version of the dataframe because we can identify the valid rows by only looking at column A:

```
>>> df1[~df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])]

   A  B  C  D
1  e  f  g  h
3  m  n  o  p
```

You can also do this with `merge`. Create a unique column in the subset dataframe. When you merge, the unique rows from the larger dataframe will have `NaN` for the column you created:

```
>>> df2['test'] = 1
>>> new = df1.merge(df2,on=['A','B','C','D'],how='left')
>>> new

   A  B  C  D  test
0  a  b  c  d     1
1  e  f  g  h   NaN
2  i  j  k  l     1
3  m  n  o  p   NaN
```

So select the rows where test == NaN and drop the test column:

```
>>> new[new.test.isnull()].drop('test',axis=1)

   A  B  C  D
1  e  f  g  h
3  m  n  o  p
```

**Edit:** @user3654387 notes that the merge method performs much better for large dataframes.

Comment: Great, thanks for the very complete answer showing several options.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: I just wanted to add some further documentation for other people reading this... The latter method mentioned above is MUCH faster than the former for big dataframes.  I tried both and didn't get a solution after 10 minutes of sorting through dataframe with 80,000 rows and 5 columns, but it only takes a few seconds for the latter merge method.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @user3654387, I edited the answer to indicate the better performance of the `merge` method.